# Скомпилировать AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

Есть у меня файл: [AndroidManifest.xml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52068915/AndroidManifest.xml)

Так вот я хочу чтобы приложение было на полный экран. Значит я декомпилировал этот файл с помощью http://www.cherubicsoft.com/android/androidmanifest.xml

В файл добавил

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Иначе вообще никакой магии не происходило. Потом в папке, где лежит `aapt.exe` создал папки: `assets` и `res`. И положил туда переименованный свой `apk` в `jar` файл `before.jar` и заменил там файл `AndroidManifest.xml` на вот такой: http://pastebin.com/1c6Jsyzg

Запускаю

```
aapt.exe package -f -m -J src -M AndroidManifest.xml -S res -A assets -0 "" -I before.jar -F MyApp.apk
```

Нихрена ничего не работает, только куча ошибок. Как этот файл наконец-таки скомпилить? Исходников apk файла нет, т.к. создавал его тут: http://www.appsgeyser.com

Вообще по идее мне нужно приложение, которое показывает определенный сайт на полный экран, без статус бара.

Comment: Забил и поставил phonegap. Как я понял, у 4 андроида на планшетах вообще нельзя убрать навигационный бар снизу. Только если под рутом с помощью программ. Как тогда игры и видео делают на весь экран?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще общий ход сборки Android приложения по шагам такой:

1. Генерация `R.java` и компиляция ресурсов `/res`, `/assets`, `AndroidManifest.xml` с помощью `aapt`
2. Компиляция Java исходников с помощью обычного `javac` компилятора - то есть `*.java` переходят в `*.class`
3. Перекодирование объектников из JVM байткодов в Dalvik байткоды. Утилита `dx`, которая превращает набор `*.class` в `classes.dex`
4. Упаковка ресурсов и объектников в `.apk` - опять же через `aapt`
5. Подписывание `apk`
6. Оптимизация архива через утилиту `zipalign`

Как нетрудно заметить `aapt` используется двояко - в первый раз для генерации `R.java`, а во второй для упаковки ресурсов в APK.

ИМХО у вас все свалено в одну кучу и генерация `R.java` и упаковка ресурсов.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще дебаггинг приложений под Android( APK-пакетов ) происходит в 3-4 этапа. Основа всех манипуляций - JAVA утилита apktool.jar, которая занимается сборкой-разборкой APK архива.

При "разборке" в таком случае APK превратится в папку, содержащую скомпилированные .smali файлы, содержащие код JAVA на низкоуровневом языке SMALI( такого рода Android-ассемблер ), ресурсы и, собственно, сам файл манифеста, где и указываются описания Activity ( включая их темы ). После декомпиляции с помощью APKTOOL и последующего редактирования AndroidManifest.xml можно собирать все обратно в Android Package( APK ). И в конце, пакет необходимо будет подписать своим ключом.

Например, разборка пакета( декомпиляция ) будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
java -jar apktool.jar -d d Package.APK /directory/package
```

Обо всем этом хорошо расписано [здесь( + на русском )](http://boomik.ru/polnaya-dekompilyaciya-android-prilozhenij)